# Ethers - What is the use of the Interface class?

Tags: ethers.js, typescript

I'm just getting started with using the Ethers library, and I'd like to understand more about the `Interface` class. Why do we use it? And under what use cases will it be useful to use `Interface`?

From an example:

```
const abiInterface: Interface = new Interface(myContractAbi)
```

I understand that this is to create an object representing the ABI, but why not just import the ABI directly from the JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why is `Interface`

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to know why Ethers even bothers with an `Interface` class, and doesn't rely on scraping the ABI from the contract's JSON data.

I don't specifically know their reasoning, but I'll try to reason about it a few different ways.

The first is, put simply, where does Ethers necessarily have the contract's JSON data from? Maybe you mean to say that if it's a contract on a live network, Ethers should check if it's verified on Etherscan and Sourcify, and grab the JSON from them if it is. Even if this would be the case, it wouldn't yield anything other than bytecode for unverified contracts, and also wouldn't help during smart contract development. There are ways to guess certain parts of the ABI from bytecode, but they aren't comprehensive.

If you accept that, it means that you'll have to be feeding Ethers the contract data anyway.

Another way of looking at it is that Ethers then could really use a class for parsing the ABI in a way that makes it useful. Just importing the ABI from the JSON would still leave a burden on the user, even to do simple tasks like list the functions. The tasks of writing helper scripts to do tasks like list functions based on the ABI would be needlessly replicated across any user who wants to do so. What's more, Ethers itself needs information like that in order to provide Contract objects that can be interacted with. Once it's already implemented in Ethers, why *not* expose it too?

Lastly, Ethers also supports an alternative ABI format: [Human-Readable ABIs](https://blog.ricmoo.com/human-readable-contract-abis-in-ethers-js-141902f4d917). As a result, Ethers needs a class that not only needs to know how to parse canonically-encoded ABIs, but also these.

### What is `Interface`

You also ask what `Interfaces` are useful for. By looking at the [docs](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/abi/interface/) you can see that it's useful for listing functions, events, and errors on contracts, and also providing information about them.

Past that, the encoding can be very useful for constructing data payloads for interacting with functions. While this is generally abstracted away by other tooling, there are certainly usecases for people rolling their own.

The decoding and parsing functions are useful for being able to process raw scraped data, for example, logs from events using `decodeEventLog` if you know which event they're from, and `parseLog` if you don't. With the interface, scraped log data can be processed into its specific components. ([This](https://medium.com/linum-labs/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-events-and-logs-on-ethereum-fec84ea7d0a5) article describes how to do this in a snippet towards the end, look for the part about Ethers v5. It only uses `decodeEventLog`, the use case there seems to be looking for a particular event (like `Transfer`), if you're looking for more events, `parseLog` probably makes more sense.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! That was super helpful and I have a better understanding now :)